Django Rest API returns category and all subcategories not just the ones selected
I wrote a category model that also has a parent part to allow subcategories. I created the serializers for excursions and for category. I long to Django admin panel and add in my categories. I then add an excursion, think of it as a post, and select the categories. In Django admin screen, it’s a multi select window and I can see categories and subcategories as well.
When I hit the api to view it, what’s returned is the category with all the subcategories that are under it. If I select a sub category as well it returns that on its own but not nested under its parent in the json.
Below is my code.
# Category model
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # This part allows for subcategories to be created. 
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='subcategories', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    # Distinguish category usage for filtering.
    # TODO: Should these be set to TRUE by default?
    for_excursion = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_event = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_destination = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Here is the excursion serializer
# Excursions model
class Excursions(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='excursion_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    data_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, limit_choices_to={'for_excursion': True}, blank=True, related_name='excursions')

    # Adding in the ability to select destinations and events for excursions.
    destinations = models.ManyToManyField('Destination', related_name='excursions')


    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# Category model
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # This part allows for subcategories to be created. 
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='subcategories', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    # Distinguish category usage for filtering.
    # TODO: Should these be set to TRUE by default?
    for_excursion = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_event = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_destination = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Excursions model
class Excursions(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='excursion_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    data_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, limit_choices_to={'for_excursion': True}, blank=True, related_name='excursions')

    # Adding in the ability to select destinations and events for excursions.
    destinations = models.ManyToManyField('Destination', related_name='excursions')


    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


Here is the API View

# EXCURSION SPECIFIC APIs
class ExcursionListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        excursions = Excursions.objects.all()
        serializer = ExcursionsListPublicSerializer(excursions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)




I have tried a few different things. Added a selected category. But still had the same result.

Share the APIView/ViewSet.

EXCURSION SPECIFIC APIs
class ExcursionListView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
excursions = Excursions.objects.all()
serializer = ExcursionsListPublicSerializer(excursions, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
